How best to handle mongoose/mongodb connections
Was wondering if it's ok to just setup a db connection on an express node server in the main express startup file like below or should I be opening and closing a connection when needed? Most of the examples I've seen they just do it upon app startup, but not sure if that's a good practice.
connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDb");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error connecting to mongo:", error);
  });

